# Can't seem to cast from interface to my struct for a list

Tags: c#

I have a function that returns a list of an interface called `IPathfindingNode`.

I created a struct that implements the interface:

```
public struct Node : IPathfindingNode
{
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }
}
```

I call a function that returns a list of the interface:

```
public List<IPathfindingNode> FindPath(Vector2Int startPoint, Vector2Int targetPoint)
```

When i try to assign the result i get an error saying i cannot assign it to my list, but i do not understand why.

```
List<Node> path = Map.FindPath(startPoint, targetPoint);
```

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Pathfinding.IPathfindingNode>'
> to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Grids.Node>'

How do i cast this correctly ? I tried `as List<Node>();` but still would not correctly convert.

Comment: Why did you choose to make `Node` a struct? When you add it to the list, the only way it can store an interface reference is by boxing it, so that's what happens. If you were trying to avoid the allocations, know that they're happening anyway.

Comment: Aren't classes boxed too? I was trying to write it where it would support either a class or a struct since I am trying to write to for any one to use, people might use a struct or a class for what ever reason.

Comment: Boxing is a *value type* feature. It boxes (wraps) the *value type* in an `object` and places it on the heap.

Comment: Classes are always allocated on the managed heap, so there's no boxing needed. Boxing allocates space for a value type on the managed heap and copies it to that memory. What you're doing is fine as long as you're aware that structs get boxed when they're used this way and not expecting something else.

Comment: Is there a way to write it to disallow structs then for my interface?

Comment: What is the type FindPath() returns?

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy i show it in the question, it says `List<IPathfindingNode>`

Comment: No. An interface cannot limit its implementors to just reference types. You can use reflection to check the type of the list elements, but that would be a lot of overhead and the consumer will have already done what you aimed to prevent.

Comment: Ah okay, i guess i am trying too hard to make the library strict to use to prevent user error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disregarding any other problem, you could just use [`Cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netcore-3.1)

> Casts the elements of an IEnumerable to the specified type.

```
List<Node> path = Map.FindPath(startPoint, targetPoint)
                     .Cast<Node>()
                     .ToList()
```

If `FindPath` returns other non `Node` implementations of `IPathfindingNode` you could use [`OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netcore-3.1)

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

Comment: What is this code doing behind the scenes? I presume creating a new list and copying across with the new type for each element ?

Comment: @WDUK Yes it is indeed doing that